# Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect when running Oracle tutorial example

Tags: java, http

I copied the sample program from Oracle Docs and I am running it "as is" in Eclipse.

However, every time run it I get a `ConnectionException`. Do I need to configure anything else? Also, my understanding on this matter is quite weak, could you please recommend beginner guide regarding Java Web programming.

The code is

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And the exception I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

I am able to access `http://www.oracle.com` via chrome and I have internet access. If it is the firewall issue, could anyone please tell me how do I solve this firewall issue?

Comment: Do you have a proxy server configured for chrome? Which OS?

Comment: Try using something like Chrome Poster. Oracle.com may be refusing requests that appear blatantly programmatic (a la DDOS)

Comment: My guess is firewall. You can use sniffers (like Fiddler) to see what's going on with the request.

Comment: I am using Windows. By looking at Google chrome settings it seams that proxy is configured. It says "Google Chrome is using your computer's system proxy settings to connect to the network." However, when I click on "Proxy settings", i just get standard Internet Option dialog box

Answer (score 4):

I have taken your code, and run it locally in my eclipse environment. It works and produces output like:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html  lang="en-US" class="no-js">
> <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>    var _U = "undefined";
>    var g_HttpRelativeWebRoot = "/ocom/";
>    var SSContributor = false;
>    var SSForceContributor = false;
>    var SSHideContributorUI = false;
>    var ssUrlPrefix = "/us/";
>    var ssUrlType = "2";
>
>    var g_navNode_Path = new Array();
>        g_navNode_Path[0] = '8';
>    var g_ssSourceNodeId = "8";
>    var g_ssSourceSiteId = "ocomen";
> </script>
> .....
> ```

This leaves a problem, because the failure is not part of your program, but part of your environment.

As I was typing this answer, you added that you have proxy settings.

You should add `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` to the run box for your application, or add:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

on the first line of your main method. This is [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html):

> **java.net.useSystemProxies** (default: false)
>
> On recent Windows systems and on Gnome 2.x systems it is possible to
>   tell the java.net stack, setting this property to true, to use the
>   system proxy settings (both these systems let you set proxies globally
>   through their user interface). Note that this property is checked only
>   once at startup.

That should pull in the system proxy settings....

There are a number of factors which could apply:

1. Your network infrastructure does not allow your program to connect to the net directly. Many locations use proxy settings to get through firewalls, etc. Do you have a proxy for your browser? You can set the system property: `java.net.useSystemProxies` to true and hope that it will pull in the system properties.
2. Your windows personal firewall normally prompts you to let applications connect to the net. Have you denied/allowed your program to connect?
3. lots of other things....
4. There could

Comment: Modified to pull in the proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. I have added this statement at top of the main method, System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");  However, I am still getting same exception. Could I try anything else

Comment: There are lots of things you can try, which is what the problem is, now. I suggest you research how to find your proxy settings, and specify them manually, and see if that works. There are a lot of reasons this could be failing, too many to make it a Java answer.

Comment: The reason behind writing the program was because I wanted to simulate multiple http request to test some local program. But I managed to do that using Fiddler. I would give another go at home computer to see if the program works or not. Most probably it would be some firewall settings at work.